# Opengl-3 programming on old laptop hardware

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I'm interested in doing some initial development targeting OpenGL 3. Unfortunately, my hardware is ~6 years out of date, and it doesn't look like ATI provides any drivers for my video card which support the newer OpenGL API's.

Are there any software implementations of the OpenGL 3 API's? I'm aware the performance will likely be dreadfully slow, but it'd be enough to hold me over until I can purchase a new laptop :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mesa 3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/) is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but it looks like the latest version only supports Opengl 2.1. And I need it to work in Windows too!

Comment: @Michael: I didn't say it was good -- only that it was about as good as you're likely to find (and it does work on Windows).

Comment: @Michael: Mesa works on Windows as well; and although OpenGL 3 support is incomplete, it does have several OpenGL 3 and OpenGL 4 extensions. You might want to check first whether the OpenGL 3 feature you're intending to use is already available in Mesa. Or, if the feature you're intending is not available, you can consider writing it yourself and contribute the code to Mesa's project.